# Есть ли здесь уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация

…они создали новые уникальные производства, которые сегодня (,) на фоне уходящих с рынка «минхиммашевских» арматурных заводов, по сути, создают новую отрасль арматуростроения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обстоятельственный оборот желательно обособить, так как он поясняет содержание наречия "сегодня", то есть определяет рыночную ситуацию сегодняшнего дня.